# How to detect if Enter event triggered by DropDown event for a ComboBox (c#)

Tags: c#, combobox

I want my combobox's dropdown list to be shown with combobox enter event. That's easy just by adding `cmb_box.DroppedDown = true;` in the `Enter` event, i know but if the user opens the list by clicking the arrow button, the list pops up then closes itself. I tried adding

```
 if (!cmb_box.DroppedDown) cmb_box.DroppedDown = true;
```

but didn't help. I even tried to define a global var to set it true on `DropDown` event and false on `DropDownClosed` event and check it in `Enter` event but that didn't work either. So i guess i need to detect if `Enter` event triggered by `DropDown` event in `Enter` method. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you change the combobox's content/items during the event?

Comment: Yup but it does not matter cuz i even tried it with an empty combobox and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can write like this

```
private void textBox4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyChar == '\r')//Enter Key
  {
     cmb_box.Focus();
     cmb_box.DroppedDown = true;
  }
}
```

textBox4 is the control before the combobox(cmb_box) control

Comment: I guess you've mistaken the point sir. `Enter` event i'm talking about is focusing not hitting Enter key.

Comment: Check above code with your example...........textBox4_KeyPress this event is for the control before the combobox(cmb_box)